# wicket - page expired when click previous button

Tags: wicket, wicket-7

I use wicket 7 with Stateful pages and every i change to new page i always use code like this:

```
PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
setResponsePage(new SecondPage(pageParameters));
```

Every i change page, a new page version is created and the page ID is increased by one. 
But when I'm trying to load the previous page, i click the previous button from the browser, the page always expired.

i found the problem when i use this getApplication in my program i cant load the previous page. if i exclude getApplication i can load the previous page.

```
public class BasePage extends WebPage {

  private ServletContext servletContext;
  private boolean developmentMode;

  public BasePage() {

    NextApp app = (NextApp) getApplication();      
    servletContext = app.getServletContext();
    developmentMode = app.usesDevelopmentConfig();

    /** other code **/
   }
}
```

Please help me, how to use getApplication and i can load the previous page too?

Comment: what is your sesion  expiry time `<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>` can you increase and check .

Comment: @soorapadman i already set the `<session-timeout> ` but when i click the previous button it will expired immediately

Comment: It's really weird . It will not because you are saying all the pages creating page ID , Did you set version for Form also . because form will not have versioned . And top of that martin has answered well . If this cont solve your issue you need to come up with more details.IMO

Comment: @randy did you fix the issue?

Comment: no.. i cant fix the issue.. @soorapadman can you help me give me the best example to code Stateful pages?

Comment: I am happy to help you out. But by this detail i don't think i can resolve your issue. look like just giving example will not resolve your issue.It seems you done correct in my sense.

Comment: @soorapadman i found another bug, every change page from menu header the page ID increased by two.. i still dont know why it happen.. i think may be because of that why i cant use previouse button.

Comment: its really strange can you update the question with more details so that we can sorted out?

Comment: @soorapadman Hei.. i found why all this happen.. i will update my question

Comment: what are you doing with development mode?

Comment: @soorapadman just some to do and that,, the problem is when i use `getApplication()` i can't load the previous page..

Answer (score 0):

`PageExpiredException`'s javadoc says:

```
 Thrown when a {@link Page} instance cannot be found by its id in the page stores. The page may be
 * missing because of reasons like:
 * <ul>
 * <li>the page have never been stored there, e.g. an error occurred during the storing process</li>
 * <li>the http session has expired and thus all pages related to this session are erased too</li>
 * <li>the page instance has been erased because the store size exceeded</li>

 * @see HttpSession#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)
 * @see org.apache.wicket.settings.StoreSettings#setMaxSizePerSession(org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Bytes)
 * @see NotSerializableException
```

Check whether any of these is true.

Also I'd recommend you to use: `setResponsePage(SecondPage.class,
 new PageParameters());`

Comment: i already try use implements Serializable and setResponsePage(SecondPage.class, new PageParameters()); but the result stil the same..